# Typescript interface with named property and arbitrarily-named index properties of different type

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

I would like to create an interface for an object that has a certain type for a specific named property and a different type for all other properties.

How would I write a definition for `foo` below?

```
let foo = {
   size: 3,
   a: 'foo',
   b: 'bar',
   c: 'baz'
}
```

This would be my intuitive approach:

```
interface Foo {
    size: number;
    [name: string]: string;
}
```

However, TypeScript tries to apply the general definition to the specific definition and triggers the following error:

```
error TS2411: Property 'size' of type 'number' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this (I don't know if it will work in TS v1.5):

```
interface Size {
    size: number;
}

interface StringMap {
    [name: string]: string;
}

type Foo = Size & StringMap;
```

Comment: You can also inline this if you'd like (also not 100% sure about ts 1.5).

    type Foo = {size: number} & {[name: string]: string};

Answer (score 5):

Without defining every property, that's expected, but you can do this:

```
interface Foo1 {
    size: number;
    [name: string]: string|number;
}
```

Better than using `any`.