# Typescript interface with indexer and other properties

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a definition file for the server-side API of ArangoDB. This API exposes a `db` object that can be used to access the collections, but also perform database-level operations like running queries. So I can call:

```
db['my-collection'] <- returns a collection object
```

but also:

```
db._query('some query') <- returns a query cursor
```

So I tried the following interface:

```
interface ArangoDatabase {
    [collectionName: string]: ArangoCollection;
    _query(query: string): ArangoCursor;
}
```

but that doesn't look valid to TS as it generates the following error:

```
Property '_query' of type '(query: string) => ArangoCursor' is not assignable to string index type 'ArangoCollection'.
```

**Note:** I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561645/typescript-interface-with-named-property-and-arbitrarily-named-index-properties) by giving the indexer a type of `ArangoCollection|ArangoCursor` but it didn't help.

Am I hitting a limit of what can be modelled with an interface, or is there another way around?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use intersection types. Try this:

```
interface ArangoDatabaseIndex {
  [collectionName: string]: ArangoCollection;
}
interface ArangoDatabaseQuery {
  _query(query: string): ArangoCursor;
}

type ArangoDatabase = ArangoDatabaseIndex & ArangoDatabaseQuery;
```

Comment: Can an intersection type be exposed by a definition file?

Comment: @ThomasWeiss Why not?

Answer (score 4):

Type of *query* member is `(query: string)=>ArangoCursor`, that's why `ArangoCollection|ArangoCursor` union didn't work for you.

It should be:

```
interface ArangoDatabase {
    [collectionName: string]: ArangoCollection|((query: string)=>ArangoCursor);
    _query(query: string): ArangoCursor;
}
```

Comment: nice, didn't know this was possible

Comment: Thanks for that correction; I've accepted st_huck's answer though as it matches better the type system I'm mapping.